# Scalar function fn_cdc_get_min_lsn() constantly returns '0x00000000000000000000' for valid table names?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, cdc

I have Change Data Capture (CDC) activated on my MS SQL 2008 database and use the following code to add a new tabel to the data capture:

```
EXEC sys.sp_cdc_enable_table
@source_schema ='ordering',
@source_name ='Fields',
@role_name = NULL,
@supports_net_changes = 0;
```

However, whenever I try to select the changes from the tracking tables using the `sys.fn_cdc_get_min_lsn(@TableName)` function

```
 SET @Begin_LSN = sys.fn_cdc_get_min_lsn('Fields')
```

I always get the zero value.

I tried adding the schema name using the following spelling:

```
 SET @Begin_LSN = sys.fn_cdc_get_min_lsn('ordering.Fields')
```

but this didn't help.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

My mystake was to assume that `sys.fn_cdc_get_min_lsn()` accepts the table name. I was mostly misguided by the examples in MSDN documentation, probably and didn't check the exact meaning of the parameters.

It turns out that the `sys.fn_cdc_get_min_lsn()` accepts the **capture instance name**, not table name!

A cursory glance at my current capture instances:

```
SELECT capture_instance FROM cdc.change_tables
```

returns the correct parameter name:

```
ordering_Fields
```

So, **one should use underscore as schema separator**, and not the dot notation as it is common in SQL Server.

Comment: ...though as @kevin points out, just replacing the dot isn't always going to work

Comment: I'm sure you are correct, but even when I copy paste the instance name from `cdc.change_tables` directly into `fn_cdc_get_min_lsn`, I get the dreaded `0x00`

Comment: April 2021, this helped me.. Thanks @alexander-galkin
I somehow mis-interpreted the parameter value as well.

Comment: In addition, it's also necessary to check if the SQL server agent is turned on.

Answer (score 2):

The above answer is correct.  Alternatively you can add an additional parameter **capture_instance** to the cdc enable

```
EXEC sys.sp_cdc_enable_table
@source_schema ='ordering',
@source_name ='Fields',
@capture_instance = 'dbo_Fields'
@role_name = NULL,
@supports_net_changes = 0;
```

then use the capture_instance string in the min_lsn function

```
SET @Begin_LSN = sys.fn_cdc_get_min_lsn('dbo_Fields')
```

will return the first LSN, and not 0x00000000000000000000.

This is partiularly useful when trying to solve the error
*"An insufficient number of arguments were supplied for the procedure or function cdc..."* from SQL when calling

```
cdc_get_net_changes_Fields(@Begin_LSN, sys.fn_cdc_get_max_lsn(), 'all')
```

Which simply means *"LSN out of expected range"*

Comment: i think you missed a comma after `@capture_instance = 'dbo_Fields'`, and i think it should be `fn_cdc_get_net_changes_Fields` ... but also this doesn't fix the issue for me :(

Answer (score 2):

I know this is mostly already explained in this post but I thought I would put together my evenings journey through CDC

1. This error:

> > "An insufficient number of arguments were supplied for the procedure or function cdc..."

Is probably caused by your low LSN being `0x00`

This in turn might be because you put the wrong instance name in with `fn_cdc_get_min_lsn`.

Use `SELECT * FROM cdc.change_tables` to find it

**Lastly make sure you use binary(10)** to store your LSN. If you use just `varbinary` or `binary`, you will again get `0x00`. This is clearly payback for me scoffing at all those noobs using `varchar` and wondering why their strings are truncated to one character.

Sample script:

```
declare @S binary(10)
declare @E binary(10)

SET @S = sys.fn_cdc_get_min_lsn('dbo_YourTable')
SET @E = sys.fn_cdc_get_max_lsn()

SELECT @S, @E

SELECT * 
FROM [cdc].[fn_cdc_get_net_changes_dbo_issuedToken2]
(
@S,@E,'all'
)
```