# CDC Function not displaying information from past day

Tags: sql-server, function, t-sql, sql-server-2014, cdc

I'm using SQL Server 2014 (SP2).

I have enabled CDC on a table.  I then want to view all that has happened in the past 24 hours so I'm using the below:

```
DECLARE @begin_time DATETIME, @end_time DATETIME, @begin_lsn BINARY(10), @end_lsn BINARY(10); 
SELECT @begin_time = GETDATE()-1, @end_time = GETDATE(); 
SELECT @begin_lsn = sys.fn_cdc_map_time_to_lsn('smallest greater than', @begin_time); 
SELECT @end_lsn = sys.fn_cdc_map_time_to_lsn('largest less than or equal', @end_time); 
SELECT * 
FROM [MyDatabase].cdc.fn_cdc_get_all_changes_dbo_MyTable(@begin_lsn,@end_lsn,'all') 
GO
```

But I keep receiving the below error:

```
An insufficient number of arguments were supplied for the procedure or function cdc.fn_cdc_get_all_changes_ ... .
```

However ,the above function is system generated when I enabled CDC and only contains 3 parameters:

```
ALTER function [cdc].[fn_cdc_get_all_changes_dbo_MyTable]
(   @from_lsn binary(10),
    @to_lsn binary(10),
    @row_filter_option nvarchar(30)
)
```

Why is the function not working?

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16299422/an-insufficient-number-of-arguments-were-supplied-for-the-procedure-or-function

Comment: Does this answer your question? [An insufficient number of arguments were supplied for the procedure or function cdc.fn\_cdc\_get\_all\_changes\_](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16299422/an-insufficient-number-of-arguments-were-supplied-for-the-procedure-or-function)

Comment: thanks @jean but I'm afraid not, the values returned are not zero value

Comment: What the answer tells us is the error message is, in fact, not warning about missing parameters bad rather there is one parameter with a bad (too big or to little) value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If the specified LSN range does not fall within the change tracking
>   timeline for the capture instance, the function returns error 208 ("An
>   insufficient number of arguments were supplied for the procedure or
>   function cdc.fn_cdc_get_all_changes.").

According to this explanation, you might need to determine`@begin_time` and `@end_time`
Such as you can specify the begin time and end time according to __$start_lsn of the CDC table. If you execute the following query you will not experience an error.

```
DECLARE @begin_time DATETIME, @end_time DATETIME, @begin_lsn BINARY(10), @end_lsn BINARY(10); 
--SELECT @begin_time = GETDATE()-1, @end_time = GETDATE(); 
SELECT @begin_time=sys.fn_cdc_map_lsn_to_time(MIN(__$start_lsn))  FROM AdventureWorks2017.cdc.dbo_MyTable_CT
SELECT @end_time = sys.fn_cdc_map_lsn_to_time(MAX(__$start_lsn)) FROM AdventureWorks2017.cdc.dbo_MyTable_CT
SELECT @begin_lsn = sys.fn_cdc_map_time_to_lsn('smallest greater than', @begin_time); 
SELECT @end_lsn = sys.fn_cdc_map_time_to_lsn('largest less than or equal', @end_time); 
SELECT * 
FROM AdventureWorks2017.cdc.fn_cdc_get_all_changes_dbo_MyTable(@begin_lsn, @end_lsn, N'all') 

+------------------------+------------------------+--------------+----------------+----+----------+------------+-------------------------+
|      __$start_lsn      |       __$seqval        | __$operation | __$update_mask | Id | SomeText | ModifiedBy |      ModifiedDate       |
+------------------------+------------------------+--------------+----------------+----+----------+------------+-------------------------+
| 0x0000002E000070F80004 | 0x0000002E000070F80003 |            2 | 0x0F           |  2 | SomeText | Matt       | 2020-02-18 14:38:00.120 |
+------------------------+------------------------+--------------+----------------+----+----------+------------+-------------------------+
```

Comment: there are no ModifiedDate fields in the CDC table